# jquery animate question

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Ok so I have this form.  In the form is an input field, that when you type a ? somewhere in the input value, I have a section of code that runs an onkeyup that slides out an element (.searchEnter) as well as changing some css.

```
<script>

                $(".askInput").keyup(function() {

                    if ($(this).val().indexOf("?") != -1) {

                        $('.searchEnter').animate({
                        marginLeft: "310px"
                        }, 200 );
                        $('.form1').get(0).setAttribute('action', 'post.php');


                    } else {

                        $('.searchEnter').animate({
                            marginLeft: "250px"
                            }, 200 );
                        $('.form1').get(0).setAttribute('action', 'search.php');


                    }



                });

                </script>
```

When I just type a question mark in the input, .searchEnter slides out right away.  However, the more characters that are preceding the question mark, (i.e. What is your name? (17 characters before ?) ), the longer it takes for the .animate to kick in and slide .searchEnter out.  Why is this occurring, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try $('.searchEnter').stop().animate ...

Answer (score 0):

It's queueing all the animations. Call [`stop`](http://api.jquery.com/stop) before calling [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate).

So instead of this:

```
$(".searchEnter").animate(...
```

Do this:

```
$(".searchEnter").stop().animate(...
```

Also, I notice you're using `get(0).setAttribute(...`. Why not just use [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr)?

Comment: Wow, this question and answer forum rocks.  Thanks a ton all your advice helped!